# grabbing values using javascript and putting them into mailTo (firefox bug)

Tags: html, jsp, struts, struts-1

I am getting a div/list in my jsp using javascript;  so i can pass it into a mailTo HTML function(opens email template in your defualt email client); grabbing these values works in chrome but not in firefox!(it prints out "undefined" into the email instead) any help would be great!

> var order = document.getElementsByClassName("order");
>
> var elementorder = order[0].innerText;

```
<div class ="order">
<logic:presentname="serviceDeskForm" property="handsetData">
<logic:iterate id="element6a" name="serviceDeskForm" property="handsetData">
<bean:write name="element6a" property="handsetManufacturer"/><bean:write name="element6b" property="handsetModel" />
<bean:write name="element6c" property="handsetQty" />
<bean:write name="element6c" property="powerSupplyQty" />
<br></logic:iterate>
</logic:present>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you assign an ID to the email to the node you want. Then you just do

```
 document.getElementById("my-id").property; //or whatever your property name is.
```